# how to append a hidden input with the text of another input

Tags: jquery, forms, dom-manipulation

been struggling with this one what im trying to do is create a second hidden input field from the text in first depending on what is selected this is what ive tried:

```
  <script>
   var $extraval = $('#citycode option:selected').text();
   var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "city").val("$extraval");
   $('#form').append($(input));
  </script>
```

this is what the first select looks like

```
<select id="citycode" name="citycode">
  <option value="3439389">Asuncion</option>
  <option value="3439352">Bella Vista</option>
  <option value="3439101">Ciudad Del Este</option>
  <option value="3438735">Encarnacion</option>
</select>
```

so basically what im trying to do is create a second hidden form input with the text of this select when submited as the value of the input

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please?

Comment: I assume there is a form with id 'form' in your html? :)

Comment: Where is this code executed? It can only be performed after the DOM is ready.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be putting $extraval in apostrophes.
(Concerning .val("$extraval"); )

Comment: thanks for the comments yes there were 2 errors first was the placement put the code in the form works fine also added submit function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that it's inside `#form`, I found two errors:

- You don't have to use `"` when you try to set `input` value passing `$extraval` as parameter.
- input is already a jQuery object, so to append it you have to do the following: `.append(input)`

Try the following:

```
var extraval = $('#citycode option:selected').text();
var $input = $("<input>", {
    'type': 'hidden',
    'name': 'city',
    'value': extraval
});
$('#form').append($input);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/UsD24/)

Answer (score 2):

Write `.val($extraval)` instead of `.val("$extraval")`. This is not PHP.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FnBDP/) (creates a text input instead of hidden - for visibility purposes)

Also, the selector `'#form'` expects a form in your code having the id `form`. You can get the form that the `select` is a part of by using one of these:

```
$('#citycode').closest('form').append(input);
```

or

```
input.appendTo($('#citycode').prop('form'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  <script>
   var extraval = $('#citycode option:selected').text();
   var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "city").val(extraval);
   $('#form').append($(input));
  </script>
```

try this code

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/pWkDR/.. This is what you should do

CODE:

```
var $extraval = "yourtext";
var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "city").val($extraval);
$('body').append(input);

// check in inspect element your  hidden field is there with data
```

Comment: Please don't post only links as answers. Post also the relevant parts of the code and maybe an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

ok so thanks for all the help everyone this is how i got it working

```
<script>
  $('#form').submit(function() {
  var extraval = $('#citycode option:selected').text();
  var $input = $("<input>", {
   'type': 'hidden',
   'name': 'city',
   'value': extraval
   });
  $('#form').append($input);
 });
</script>
```

placed at the end of the form works great